# Joining three tables using UNION query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, union

What I'm trying to do is to pull unique sets of data from three different tables and display them together using a UNION query. There's one field that they all have in common, so they should be linked via that field. I'm getting an error when I try to run the query that says "Unable to execute query. Invalid operation or syntax using multi-value field." I know which field is causing the problem, it's the "Line of Business" field. How would I fix this so that the query is able to handle it? Is it even possible?

Here's the SQL statement I'm using:

```
SELECT [Financial Bureau Reports].[Date Year], [Financial Bureau Reports].[Section Chief].[Financial Bureau Reports].[Outcome], [Financial Bureau Reports].[Type of Review]
FROM [Financial Bureau Reports]
WHERE (([Financial Bureau Reports].[CoCode (NAIC)]=[Forms]![Home Screen]![txtCoCode]))

UNION ALL

SELECT [Market Analysis Review].[Data Year], [Market Analysis Review].[Review Level], [Market Analysis Review].[Line of Business].[value], [Market Analysis Review].[Recommendation], [Market Analysis Review].[Analyst], [Market Analysis Review].[Action]
FROM [Market Analysis Review]
WHERE(([Market Analysis Review].[CoCode (NAIC)]=[Financial Bureau Reports].[CoCode(NAIC)]))

UNION ALL 

SELECT [MarketConductExams].[State], [MarketConductExams].[Report Date]
FROM [MarketConductExams]
WHERE [MarketConductExams].[CoCode (NAIC)]=[Market Analysis Review].[CoCode (NAIC)];
```

Sorry about the lack of formatting, apparently SQL doesn't transfer over that well.

Also, I'm using SQL in Microsoft Access 2010.

Let me know if the question is too vague or needs clarification. Thanks!

Comment: At a minimum, you can highlight the code block and ctl-k or click the `{ }` button to format as a code block.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot union together queries which do not have the same number of columns in the select.  These don't even seem to be related queries that should be unioned together. I think you need to send three separate queries to your application.

Answer (score 1):

I normally have an outer SELECT around the unions but the others are right, you need to have the same number of fields and the same names for those fields.

Use AS to sync the field names.
If you have some fields that are not in the other queries then you can manufacture them: null as SomeOutputField or '' as SomeOutputField.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're getting that message in particular, but UNION statements require that each SELECT statement has the same number of columns and that they be of the same data type. That's not true of the SQL statement you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to JOIN your tables to each other, not UNION them together - like so:

```
SELECT [Financial Bureau Reports].[Date Year], 
       [Financial Bureau Reports].[Section Chief].[Financial Bureau Reports].[Outcome], 
       [Financial Bureau Reports].[Type of Review],
       [Market Analysis Review].[Data Year], 
       [Market Analysis Review].[Review Level], 
       [Market Analysis Review].[Line of Business].[value], 
       [Market Analysis Review].[Recommendation], 
       [Market Analysis Review].[Analyst], 
       [Market Analysis Review].[Action],
       [MarketConductExams].[State], 
       [MarketConductExams].[Report Date]
FROM [Financial Bureau Reports]
(JOIN [Market Analysis Review]
   ON [Market Analysis Review].[CoCode (NAIC)]=[Financial Bureau Reports].[CoCode(NAIC)]
 (JOIN [MarketConductExams]
    ON [MarketConductExams].[CoCode (NAIC)]=[Market Analysis Review].[CoCode (NAIC)]))
WHERE [Financial Bureau Reports].[CoCode (NAIC)]=[Forms]![Home Screen]![txtCoCode];
```

Comment: Makes sense. I tried it, and I'm getting an error that tells me there's a syntax problem in the FROM field...any ideas?

Comment: Can you include the actual error message? `FROM` is the start of a clause, not a field name; if the error message is referring to a 'FROM field', then check whether your code has a comma after `[MarketConductExams].[Report Date]`. You could also try removing the `((`...`))` from around the first `ON` and the `WHERE` conditions, or adding them around the second `ON` condition.

Comment: Initially, I was getting a message that said "Syntax error in FROM clause." Now, after adding a comma after `[MarketConductExams].[Report Date]` I'm getting an error that says "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect." (I've gone through and adjusted the bracketing, too).

Comment: @GregSpev: You misunderstood my previous comment - [MarketConductExams].[Report Date] should not have a comma after it. I was trying to provide possible solutions in the absence of the actual error message (which is always a bad idea). I have read elsewhere that joined tables in Access should be enclosed within parentheses, and have amended my query accordingly - can you try the updated query?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. My mistake. Ok, I tried the query you suggested and I'm still getting the "Syntax error in FROM clause". It happened with the brackets enclosing the JOIN clause, and still an error.

Comment: @GregSpev: Try changing `JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` - in most SQL dialects, the `INNER` is optional, but it looks as though it may be mandatory in Access: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx . If it still doesn't work then it's beyond me.